# Dynamically name struts2 textfield

Tags: jsp, dynamic, struts2, textfield

I am trying to write a JSP that contains a struts 2 textfield tag as follows:

I would like to dynamically assign a name to this textfield using the value of a variable I declare earlier in the code as follows:

```
<s:if test="patient.procedureCode.size > 0">  

<% int i=0;%>  

<s:iterator value="patient.procedureCode" id ="procedureCode">      

    <%i++; %>  

    <% if((i%2) > 0) { %>    

        <tr   class="dbText" >  

            <td >  
                <s:checkbox value="false" fieldValue="%{#procedureCode.objectid}" name="objectid" theme="simple" />  
            </td>           

            <td class="BasicText" >                             
                <s:textfield value="%{proceddateVar}" size="10"  theme="simple" readonly="false" name=""/>  
            </td>  
        </tr>       
    <%} %>  

</s:iterator>
```

I would like to give the textfield a name that is equal to the current value of the variable i.
Please advice.

Comment: You mean the same value as you are assiging to the value `%{proceddateVar}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what you mean by current value of variable

but if you will do like

```
<s:textfield label="What is your name?" name="%{var_val}" />
```

this will name the text field as the current value of variable
So i believe when the iterator will iterate it will place the object on the top of value stack and you can refer this using the OGNL expression

```
id has been Deprecated. Use `var` instead
```

There are different properties of the `IteratorStatus` object so use them in place of scriplet

```
index   int             zero-based index value.
count   int             index + 1
first   boolean     returns true if it is the first element
last    boolean     returns true if it is the last element
even    boolean     returns true if the count is an even number.
odd     boolean     returns true if the count is an odd number.
modulus     int     takes an int value and returns the modulus of count
```

i personally will never prefer to mix scriplet when things can be achieved in clean way

here are the details of Iterator Object
[Iterator Status](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html)

Comment: By 'Current Value of variable' I mean the following:
A. Integer variable i was initialized to 0. 
B. During each iteration, i increments by 1. 
C. I would like to assign the current value of i (during each iteration) to the textfield thats generated in that iteration. 
D. Meaning during the first iteration, I would like the textfield to be named '0', during the second iteration '1' and so on and so forth.